# Disregarding bad input within 'for' statement in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, user-input

I am trying to write a program that loops a prompt 10 times or until the correct input is entered. Wrong input entered should not count towards the 10 tries to enter the correct input.
 I am not sure if I should keep the prompt within the for statement or not. Here is what I have so far regarding the bad input issue:

```
for i in range(10):
    value=input("Enter a numerical value: ")
    if value.isdigit()==False:
       print("Error.")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better construct to use would be a [while](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop) loop.

Instead of looping for 10 times, you could loop until you have a valid input, i.e.

```
while True:
    value = input("Enter a number:")
    if value.isdigit() == False:
        print "Error"
    else: 
        break
```

However, that said, if you only want to loop for a maximum of 10 times, the construct that you have is perfectly fine - you just need a way of exiting the loop when a valid number is entered,

```
for i in range(10):
    value=input("Enter a numerical value: ")
    if value.isdigit()==False:
        print("Error.")
    else:#is a digit
        break
```

After seeing your comment, I would still advise using while loop, just with an extra variable (and a few changes made from DarinDouglass's comment

```
times_correct = 0
while times_corrent < 10:
    value = input("Enter a number:")
    if value.isdigit() == False:
        print "Error"
    else:
        times_corrent += 1
```

Comment: Thank you, but I believe I phrased that poorly. I actually have several error checks, and if the user gives input that I deem incorrect, such as ifvalue.isdigit()==False, I want that user input to not count as an input for the 'for' statement. Basically, I want a user to be able to type in incorrect input indefinitely, but only able to type in correct inputs 10 times.

Comment: @user, in that case, I would still recommend using a while loop -- see my edit

Comment: There is no need for an infinite loop here. Simply use `while time_correct < 10`. Also, the `if value.isdigit() == False` is wordy, use `if not value.isdigit()`

Comment: @DarinDouglass - I am inclined to agree on the first point - it really does make more sense that way, however, I have not changed the value.isdigit == False - it seems easier to read that (at least to me) way even if it is wordier and more prone to error

Comment: . I understand what I was doing wrong now, I should have used 'while' from the start because the statements are dependent on user input. Thank you so much, you really helped me out with something I was stuck on for hours.

Comment: @user - no problem - you should mark an answer as accepted by clicking on the empty checkmark underneath the post score so future users know which answer helped you.

Comment: @jcw I don't think your way is more prone to error, as logically they are the same statement. I was just pointing out that using the syntax I suggested is more like Python convention.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [break the loop](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#break) when you get the correct input:

```
for i in range(10):
    value=input("Enter a numerical value: ")
    if not value.isdigit():  # PEP8 says to use `not` instead of `== False`
        print("Error.")
    else:
        break  # If we get here, the input was good.  So, break the loop.
```

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> for i in range(10):
...     value=input("Enter a numerical value: ")
...     if not value.isdigit():
...         print("Error.")
...     else:
...         break
...
Enter a numerical value: a
Error.
Enter a numerical value: b
Error.
Enter a numerical value: 12
>>>
```